# Skipped 181 frames ... Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-animation

> Skipped 181 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

that appears when i run the code and click on the activity ... why is that appearing and how to get rid of it? here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public void Dropin(View v){
    ImageView Counter = (ImageView)v;
    Counter.setTranslationY(-1000);
    Counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
    Counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);

}
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

Comment: `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` says it all, in my opinion.

Comment: As @Rotwang said, so try to add "logic work" in a asynctask (just an example) or in another class. Don't put any heavy work in where the UI main thread is.

Comment: @Carlton is right but you have to be aware that you can't access to UI-Objects from background threads... 
I don't know how 'setTranslation' and 'animate' work from background but 'Counter.setImageResource' will definitely not work in a AsyncTask or a Thread.

Comment: what is size of your image?

Comment: i tried Asynctask and it didn't work also

Comment: @saeedshahini  about 600kb..

Comment: @Carlton okay i will the another class option

Comment: can you check your code without animation? to find out what is cause of this error

Comment: @saeed shahini it runs without errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't have any computationally heavy work so far. The only place is Counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red) call. Maybe, your image is of much bigger size than you need and Android has to resize it.
Another reason - use .png() format for resources, because transition has to make lot of calculations for formats such as .jpg and .bmp

Comment: Thank you it worked ! i used .png format